# DROP trigger only if it exists (ORACLE)

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, triggers

I want to **drop** a existing trigger in **ORACLE**.

I do know the `drop` query for the trigger in **oracle**. But wanted to know that how can I check if that trigger is already exists in **Oracle DB**.

DROP query:

```
DROP TRIGGER **TRIGGER_NAME**
```

Comment: what is the reason for that?cant you just execute the query, if it doesnt exist it will throw an error.if it does, it will be dropped.

Comment: You can query `[user|all|dba]_triggers` depending on your privileges, whether you are logged in as the owner of the trigger, etc.  Or you could simply drop the trigger and catch the exception.

Comment: I'm a **delphi** developer and I'm creating this **DROP** query from code. So it is the reason I'm checking it with **oracle query**.

Comment: @brenners1302: I don't have **ORACLE DB** installed on my  machine. So forgive me for this lame question. I wanted to know that what if from code side I execute the query {DROP TRIGGER TRIGGER_NAME} and it throw error without handling any exception? All what I need to do is drop the trigger anyways. Do I need to add exception for that?

Answer (score 10):

You need a PL/SQL block with dynamic SQL for this:

```
-- drop the trigger if it exists
declare 
  l_count integer;
begin

  select count(*)
    into l_count
  from user_triggers
  where trigger_name = 'TRIGGER_NAME';

  if l_count > 0 then 
     execute immediate 'drop trigger trigger_name';
  end if;

end;
/


-- now create the trigger    
create trigger trigger_name
   ..
begin
end;
/
```

---

Note that (unquoted) identifiers are stored in upper case in the Oracle system catalogs. So make sure you use `trigger_name = 'TRIGGER_NAME'`, not `trigger_name = 'trigger_name'` in the PL/SQL check

Answer (score -1):

You have two option:

1) Check if trigger exists

```
SELECT * 
  FROM user_triggers
 WHERE trigger_name = '...'
```

2) DROP trigger and check for EXCEPTION

Comment: I don't have ORACLE DB installed on my machine. So forgive me for this lame question. I wanted to know that what if from code side I execute the query {DROP TRIGGER TRIGGER_NAME} and it throw error without handling any exception? All what I need to do is drop the trigger anyways. Do I need to add exception for that?

Comment: If trigger do not exists and you drop it, there an exception. So you just need obfuscate exception, cause 'drop trigger anyway': create or replace trigger my_trg 
before insert on tmp 
for each row 
begin
  null;
end;
 
BEGIN
  -- trigger still exists
  execute immediate 'DROP TRIGGER my_trg';
  -- no more trigger, exception raised
  execute immediate 'DROP TRIGGER my_trg';
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    NULL;
END;